# Calculating Debye functions to high accuracy (hundreds of bits), is it possible to be faster than generic quadrature?

Tags: integration, floating-point, quadrature, numerical-integration

The [Debye functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_function) are defined like so: ${D_n\left(x\right)} = {\frac{n}{x^n} \cdot {\int_0^x{\frac{t^n}{e^t - 1}dt}}}$.

I'm trying to evaluate the functions for $n$ from one to four and for $\left\lvert x \right\rvert < 10$. The required number of evaluations is great, and I require hundreds of bits of accuracy.

Using Julia and the Julia package [QuadGK](https://juliahub.com/ui/Packages/General/QuadGK), implementing the integral in the definition is simple enough, however it's slow for tiny values of $x$, and the integrand even overflows (due to the MPFR exponent not being wide enough) for very tiny values of $x$.

I wonder if there's a way compute $D_1$, $D_2$, $D_3$, $D_4$ without resorting to generic numeric integration, perhaps it would be possible to design a custom algorithm for evaluating the functions that would be faster?

Comment: That Wikipedia page shows series expansion for $D_n(x)$. Why not try it instead of integration, if the series converges fast then that would be the way to go.

Comment: The Wikipedia page linked to in the question lists multiple publications dealing with implementations of the Debye functions. Have you consulted any of those? If so, what did you find? ACM TOMS is a highly-reputed journal, so I took a brief look at the publication by MacLeod and it seems that he does *not* use quadrature. Whether it is practical to extend the method used for hundreds of bits of accuracy I cannot determine on the double.

Comment: What application requires you to have *hundreds of bits of accuracy*?

Comment: Separately, the underflow of $e^t-1$ should be addressed by using the function `expm1` instead of computing `exp(t)-1`.

Comment: There is a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377660/continued-fraction-expansion-related-to-exponential-generating-function) (with answer) about a continued fraction expansion for $D_{3}$ on Mathematics Stackexchange which looks worthy of exploration. The paper by Guseinov and Mamedov linked on the Wikipedia page likewise looks worthy of followup, as it relates the Debye functions to the incomplete gamma functions, and various arbitrary-precision packages (e.g. [ARB](https://arblib.org/)) have support for those.

Comment: Tentatively, Wolfgang's suggestion to use `expm1` seems to solve all my problems so far.

Comment: Did you mean underflow rather than overflow? The integrand is bounded when $t\to 0$.

Comment: @user2373145 I am not familiar with the Debye functions (encountered them here for the first time), but I have implemented elementary functions and special functions in a professional capacity. Generally speaking, when it comes to *performance* (your question), quadrature is rarely the best choice.

Comment: The reason I wanted more than a hundred bits of accuracy is to find some minimax polynomials for faster Debye function evaluation for binary64 floating-point afterwards. This is the result, currently being registered in Julia's General registry: https://gitlab.com/nsajko/DebyeFunctions.jl